# c# dictionary method as a value

Tags: c#, methods, dictionary

I have a class with a bunch of methods in it, the methods transfer variables elsewhere in my program when called. I want to use a dictionary as the middle man between the methods that transfer data and the methods that call them.

So here is my question. Say I make a dictionary, where the key is an `int` and I want the value to be the name of a method. I will assign a new value /  method each time I add to the dictionary. Is there a value type I can put there that will let me do this?

`Dictionary<int, ?> methodKey= new Dictionary<int, ?>();`

I tried to find a list of types that dictionary will take but I couldn't find anything specific.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have all methods the same signature (i.e. `object MethodName()`)?

Comment: Yeah they will all have the same signature

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use any delegate type as a type of value. For example:

```
Dictionary<int, Action>
```

So, you'll be able to write such things:

```
        dictionary[0] = () => Console.WriteLine("0");
        dictionary[1] = Foo;
        dictionary[2] = a.Bar;
```

Specific delegate type depends on your needs - may be, you want for methods to have some input parameters or output/return values, but it should be most common type.

Answer (score 0):

Will all the methods have the same signature? If so you can probably use one of the existing `Action` or `Func` delegate, (or you can create a delegate type with that signature), and use that as your second type parameter.

If not, you can use `Delegate` (or even `object`) and cast to the appropriate type when you invoke the delegates.